# How to decode a Base64 encoded image string and how to display that bitmap after decoding in MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-ce, pocketpc

I'm trying to develop a WinCE Pocket PC application I have to take bitmap images from an SQL server from a web service in base64 encoded data  and I want to decode that base64 encoded string and then by using that decoded result I want to create or display bitmap image in my dialog box picture control. I need to do all these things in MFC, I'm using VC++ MFC SmartDevice Project.

Comment: Please edit and fix your punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding and decoding can be done by using one of the many free resources online.  [Here's one](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/article.php/c5099/) that looks simple enough.  If shows decoding a buffer, which is probably what you have retrieved from the service.

That will decode it to another buffer, which is now a Bitmap.  Displaying that on the Window is typically (though you could certainly go myriad other ways) [done with a CStatic instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc367850.aspx).